# Could not import telegram into visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, telegram, telegram-bot

I successfully installed using the

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

on my visual code studio
But the problem is that I could not import it on my file.py. There was no telegram to import from.

I don't know how to solve the issue. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the `file.py` from your Visual Studio? You'll need to use the pip that corresponds to the python that you are using in order to have the module you installed to be present when you run the file and.